# CustomValidator in a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a custom validator inside a repeater

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="lstRepeater" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvValid" runat="server" CssClass="error" EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="Invalid."></asp:CustomValidator>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbCustomAnswer"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

As a test, I tried the following code on an OnClick event

```
    foreach(RepeaterItem item in lstRepeater.Items)
    {
        CustomValidator cvValid= (CustomValidator)item.FindControl("cvValid");
        cvValid.IsValid = false;
    }
```

As would be assumed, the error message is not displayed on the page because I didn't databind the repeater. However, as soon as re-contruct the repeater and the datasource, I lose all the old values inside the repeater. Is there an easy way around this? I can't think of an elegant way of handling this problem.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear to me.  Why and when are you reconstructing the repeater?  Why wouldn't you expect the values to be lost if you're re-binding it?

Comment: I would expect the values to be lost when re-binding. I want to display the error message without having to re-bind. However, I don't think this is possible. The only solution I can think of is saving the old values and then re-binding everything. This seems a little messy and I wanted to see if there is a simpler solution that I'm not seeing. Hopefully this makes it clearer.

Comment: I'm still a bit lost.  If you haven't databound the repeater, what "old values" are you losing that you want to be displaying error messages for?

Comment: I am losing "Old Values" in the repeater when I rebind the repeater on Page_Load.

Comment: You said you want to display the error message without having to re-bind.  Then why are you re-binding?

Comment: I would prefer to not have to re-bind, but I can't seem to find away around it.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just have the OnServerValidate function return false?

```
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvValid" runat="server" CssClass="error"EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="Invalid."OnServerValidate="ServerValidation" />
```

> 

```
void ServerValidation (object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
 {
    args.IsValid = false;
 }
```

Comment: You can do this, but you still have the same problem.

Comment: As long as you don't rebind the list on PostBack this will work.